# How to access two different snowflakes environment in one?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

we have two snowflakes environments with different user login, one is for Development and one is for Testing. both are having same schemas and tables. i want to compare COUNT of all tables from both DEV and TEST. please help with the viable options!!

I could list the COUNT from one environment by referring information_schema.tables. But need help on connect both environment and list the COUNT ...Like DBlink in Oracle

select TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,TABLE_TYPE,ROW_COUNT,CREATED,LAST_ALTERED from information_schema.tables;

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent of DBLINKS in Snowflake. The easiest solution would be to run the counts in both environments and then compare them in e.g. Excel.

Assuming the Accounts are both in the same Cloud/Region you could share the tables from one to the other and then they'd all be in a single account where you could run the comparison SQL

Answer (score 0):

The closest to the DBLink solution, in Snowflake would be the [Data Sharing](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide-data-share.html) solution, just from one account share the selected tables on the other account and you can compare data.

If your accounts are in different regions or with other cloud providers then you need to use [Database Replication](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/database-replication.html) solution, set up replication between accounts and periodically synchronize data when you want to verify it.